# Updating CarrierWave files (text) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I've figured out how to upload files using CarrierWave.  I've figured out how to then load those files into a textarea for editing.  My question is:

How do I update my CarrierWave files once they've been edited in a textarea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you store on local disk and that your config is as follows

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
end
```

then in your controller's action:

```
@user = User.find params[:id]
File.open(@user.avatar.current_path, 'r+') do |f|
   f.print params[:user][:avatar_textarea]
   f.truncate f.pos
end
```

Comment: I haven't tried this option yet.  But I will and get back to you.  I'm going to post the other solution I figured out.

Comment: This method works well. One issue:  if I upload a file, then turn of the development server and come back at a later time, previously uploaded files don't get updated.  Why could this be?

Comment: Found the problem.  The ajax call was caching the files.  Everything was being saved fine, but the browser was loading older, cached versions.  I turned of caching like this: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});`

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out by creating a ruby File with the same filename as the file being updated.  Then I populated this file with the textarea contents.  Next, I called update_attributes on the file being updated, pointing its :file attribute to the file just created.  After updating the attribute, I delete the file I created.

I tried this using Tempfile, but couldn't figure out a way to maintain the desired filename.

Comment: I'm noticing that this doesn't always work.  So far I'm only running this application in development mode.  It seems that when I shut down the server, and then restart it, the previously uploaded files (during previous rails server runs) aren't updating properly.  I wonder why this is.

Comment: Found the problem.  The ajax call was caching the files.  Everything was being saved fine, but the browser was loading older, cached versions.  I turned of caching like this: `$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});`